# python Script for getting a captcha

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, captcha

So i was doing this site scraping for my app. I need to download the captcha image for displaying it to the user. But every time I visit the captcha url it generates a new captcha. How can I download the the dynamically generated captcha for automated Login

eg:https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp

Here I download the captcha using below script>>>

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
img = soup.find('img',id ='imgCaptcha')
print img
urllib.urlretrieve(img['src'],'captcha.bmp')
```

But some how this script doesn't seem to work.

1) One solution is to take screenshot and crop out the captcha.
But I need a different solution as I am going to work on devices with various screen sizes so taking screen shot would not solve the purpose.

Comment: Please remove the classic asp tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img['src']` returns a *relative* url - `captcha.asp`. You have to make it into an absolute url before you can use it (`https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp`).

```
import urlparse
urllib.urlretrieve(urlparse.urljoin(url, img['src']), 'captcha.bmp')
```